# TPM Firmware Update, Backup and Clearing

Tags: backup, updates, firmware, tpm

Windows defender is telling me "a firmware update is needed for your security processor (TPM)", i did some searching and found out basically how to update and clear the tpm, but it gave me a warning about backing up data, could someone please explain both what the data that i need to backup is, and how to back it up.

Edited: I dont have or use or whatever you do with bitlocker, so the other thread doesnt really help. After looking at the other thread, i still dont know what the personal data is, or how to back it up, please explain further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup before clearing TPM](https://superuser.com/questions/1321094/how-to-backup-before-clearing-tpm)

Comment: If you are not using BItLocker you need to edit your question to indicate as much.  The data you need to backup is your personal data, since it likely is currently encrypted.  Performing an update on the TPM firmware while you have BitLocker enabled is dangerous.  Be sure you have your recovery key before you do that.

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate, because the only question that exists within the body, is basically asking what data they are suppose to backup which I addressed in my answer to the duplicate.  Likewise I suspect the actual question, is what they should do about it, which I also address in my answer to the duplicate.  Since I don't know what "the last guy said" exactly.  I can't avoid submitting something that can't be understood.  I encourage you to clarify your question, if my answer, does not actually answer your question.

Comment: reworked the question, sorry

Comment: Personal data, is any data that is not a system file, which means basically any file you care about.  Are you 100% certain BitLocker is not enable on your device?  *If that is the case, then you can update TPM, without worrying about your data.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i did some searching and found out basically how to update and clear
>   the TPM, but it gave me a warning about backing up data, could someone
>   please explain both what the data that i need to backup is, and how to
>   back it up.

The warning is only applicable, if you are using BitLocker, and is informing you that if you had BitLocker enabled and you cleared your TPM then your data would be permanently lost.  To avoid that situation you should backup those files, to an external drive, and then suspend BitLocker.  You should also backup your BitLocker recovery key.

> I don't have or use or whatever you do with BitLocker

If you don't have BitLocker enabled then clearing your TPM and updating the firmware will have no affect on your personal files.  By not using BitLocker, your files are not encrypted by a key contained within the TPM, and by clearing TPM that key if existed would be lost.  Which is the reason you should backup the recovery key, if you have BitLocker enabled, before you update and clear the TPM.

> i still don't know what the personal data is, or how to back it up,

Personal data, is any file contained within your user profile, that if you no longer could access it would be a big deal.  **I suggest you just ignore the prompt.  Since BitLocker is not enabled, there isn't a reason, you should be updating the TPM firmware.**