# What are the non-Bitlocker TPM keys I need to check before clearing TPM?

Tags: windows-10, tpm

I've read the threads here (like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1323802/tpm-firmware-update-backup-and-clearing) and [this one)](https://superuser.com/questions/1321094/how-to-backup-before-clearing-tpm) on clearing TPM and the need to either suspend Bitlocker or have backups of the keys.  That's fine.

But in the [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/initialize-and-configure-ownership-of-the-tpm#clear-all-the-keys-from-the-tpm) under the section "Precautions to take before clearing the TPM" (about halfway down) they state the following:

> Clearing the TPM causes you to lose all created keys associated with
> the TPM, and data protected by those keys, such as a virtual smart
> card or a sign in PIN. Make sure that you have a backup and recovery
> method for any data that is protected or encrypted by the TPM

This sounds like I might need to backup or disable some other things. I obviously remember my Windows sign-in PIN.  I have no idea what a "virtual smart card" is.  But the open-ended nature of that description makes me worry that there's something else I don't know about.

1. Are there other things I need to worry about beside Bitlocker.
2. If so is there any sort of Windows tool to "Backup all TPM" keys?  Or perhaps to show me what keys have been created?  Or do I just have to know which ones are out there?

[EDIT]  I ran the `Get-TpmEndorsmentKeyInfo -Hash "Sha256"` command in an elevated powershell window (apologies for glossing over the suggestion before)  This was the result

```
IsPresent                : True
PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.AsnEncodedData
PublicKeyHash            : 42ff19c7660f684110b2b8b280f093df62862e558aa63bb67341cea0ff995af2
ManufacturerCertificates : {[Subject]
                             TPMManufacturer=id:4E544300 + TPMModel=NPCT75x + TPMVersion=id:72

                           [Issuer]
                             CN=Nuvoton TPM Root CA 2111 + O=Nuvoton Technology Corporation + C=TW

                           [Serial Number]
                             09C3BC22DAB3C59C0E36

                           [Not Before]
                             2/11/2019 12:55:01 AM

                           [Not After]
                             2/7/2039 12:55:01 AM

                           [Thumbprint]
                             B2094A7ED31D11941EA3D35AE6FC5D3166D5F860
                           }
AdditionalCertificates   : {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there other things I need to worry about beside BitLocker.

You indicated none of your disk are BitLocker protected.

> If so is there any sort of Windows tool to "Backup all TPM" keys?

I am not aware of any Windows software that can backup the user created keys stored in a Trusted Platform Module (TPM).  However, your TPM, does not contained any keys worth backing up.  **While your device's TPM was initialized, it's does not contain any user created keys, which means it be cleared.**

> Or perhaps to show me what keys have been created?

There are no user created keys stored in the TPM.

I guarantee your TPM is not actually being used, since BitLocker protection is not enabled, and you your definitely not using a virtual smart card. **If your sign-in pin is stored in the TPM, you can simply reinitialize your TPM and store it again.**

Comment: On a separate note, every update Dell releases is marked as urgent, it's only urgent if you actually use the TPM to store user created keys.  Unless you plan to upgrade to Windows11. I would just disable TPM with the firmware and uninstall any Dell software dealing with TPM, and then ignore the update entirely.